# UpdatePanelAnimationExtender Is not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have created an UpdatePanelAnimationExtender and everything compiles but when I run it looks like the UpdatePanelAnimationExtender does not even do anything or even get hit. It hits the button_click and changes the label text but it does not do the div resize. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

Thanks for your help in advance.

```
    <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <div style="border: dashed 1px #222222;">
    <div id="up_container" style="background-color: #40669A;">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="update" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="background" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 44px; padding: 12px; height: 44px; color: #FFFFFF;">     
                    <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" Style="padding: 5px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">
                        CLICK SAVE BUTTON
                    </asp:Label>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCommit" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<asp:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender ID="upae" BehaviorID="animation" runat="server" TargetControlID="update">
    <Animations>
        <OnUpdating>
            <Sequance>
                <ScriptAction Script="var b = $find('animation'); b._originalHeight = b._element.offsetHeight;" />
                <StyleAction Attribute="overflow" Value="hidden" />
                <Parallel duration = ".25" Fps="30">
                    <Resize Height="0" />
                </Parallel>
            </Sequance>                    
        </OnUpdating>
        <OnUpdated>
            <Sequance>
                <Parallel duration=".25" Fps="30">
                    <Resize HeightScript="$find('animation')._originalHeight" />
                </Parallel>
            </Sequance>   
        </OnUpdated>
    </Animations>        
</asp:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender>

<asp:Button ID="btnCommit" runat="server" Text="Save User" TabIndex="5" 
    onclick="btnCommit_Click" />
```

Comment: I've never had good luck having the update panel and the extender in different elements. I would first try placing the two of them within the same DIV and see where that gets you.

Comment: Hey Brad, I tried placing it within each div and running it and still did not work :( its really irritating lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extender is part of the [asp.net ajax toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/UpdatePanelAnimation/UpdatePanelAnimation.aspx). I think this means you would need to change

```xml
<asp:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender ... </asp:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender>
```

to

```xml
<ajaxToolkit:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender ... </ajaxToolkit:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender>
```

Hopefully this helps

-Update-

Sequence is misspelled in you example code. Try changing the `<Sequance>` node to be `<Sequence>` in both the updating and updated sections.

The above does work, though you can just include 
`<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>` at the top of page. `<asp:AnimationExtender>` will be the same as `<ajaxToolkit:AnimationExtender>`

Comment: Thanks for quick answer Brian, but that does not work I have my toolkit as part of Visual Studio Tool box and when I drag and drop the UpdatePanelAnimationExtender to the page it automatically added <asp:> and not <ajaxToolkit>...

Comment: That was the problem... Thanks for your help :)